# Como faço para inicializar o JFrame centralizado?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

Já tentei o `this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);` só que ele não ficou no meio da tela, eu diria que ele ficou bem mais pra direita e pra baixo do que no centro.

```
public Principal() {
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
setTitle("Menu Principal");

iniciarTela();

setSize(300, 200);
setVisible(true);
setResizable(false);
}
```

Comment: Adicione seu código ai. Esse comando é que centraliza, o problema está em outro lugar.

Comment: Tai mano, acredito que esteja da maneira certa ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso acontece porque você está tentando usar o método [`setLocationRelativeTo()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setLocationRelativeTo-java.awt.Component-) para centralizar uma tela sem ter definido seu tamanho e sem que tenha sido desenhada ainda.

Tente chamar este método após ter definido um tamanho para o Frame, como sugestão, chame-o antes exibir a tela com `setVisible()` como mostra o código abaixo:

```
public Principal() {
 setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
 setTitle("Menu Principal");

 iniciarTela();

 setSize(300, 200);
 setResizable(false);
 this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
 setVisible(true);

}
```

Comment: Valeu cara, agora eu entendi, vou ficar mais atento na hora de dar esses comandos, Obrigado !